# Drupal 10, ckeditor 5: allow content editors to add javascript

Tags: drupal, ckeditor5

How can i allow content editors (Drupal 10 website) to add javascript code in ckeditor 5?

They can click on the source button but all JS special characters are converted to html entities. So this JS code `> 0 &&` will convert to this `&gt; 0 &amp;&amp;`.

Answer (score 0):

The patch from drupal.org [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3364884#comment-15301573) can help.